# Best approach for maven multi module project

Tags: java, maven

I have problem with multi module maven project when I need to specify sub-module dependencies with parent module

Here is my configuration for pom.xml

**Parent POM:**

```
<groupId>com.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>childA</module>
    <module>childB</module>
</modules>
```

**childA POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>childA</artifactId>

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

***ChildB POM***

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>childB</artifactId>
```

I was able to build childB when running `mvn clean install` inside childB.

I am getting an error when build Parent and ChildA with error message

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project parent: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.parent:childA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.parent:parent:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I need added dependency inside childA pom.xml to parent package due to some classes available on parent package

How i should resolve this issue?

Comment: first comment out all the `module` build only parent then uncomment and build it will work . It usually will happen when you do first time .

Comment: this doesn't make sense to have a dependency on your parent. Your parent is a pom not an artifact (jar, war, ...) so you can't put a dependency in any of your children modules to the parent

Comment: That's the only valid answer here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `childA` pom makes no sense.

It has the same artifact as both dependency parent and build dependency :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

and :

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

First : the dependency resolution will never success as it is a chicken and egg problem.
The parent module that produces a pom will be available only as the reactor build is terminated but it will be terminated only as all modules, among `childA`, would terminate their build.

Second : Multi module maven project and parent module are designed to be packaged as `pom` and not as a `jar`.
Which interest to declare it as a dependency of `childA`?
Just remove it and keep it as parent of `childA`.

> I need added dependency inside childA pom.xml to parent package due to
>   some classes available on parent package

You don't need to specify it as a dependency to achieve it.
Child projects inherit many things from parent project, among dependencies.